# Understanding synchronized and implementing a queue

Tags: java, oop, synchronization, queue, synchronized

I make multiple web requests from an Android application I'm working on. I want all these requests to be processed one at a time in the order they arrive, does my below code do that?

The way I read and understand synchronized is that of all the threads I spin off, only one can be in any of the below methods at one time. For example, if a user tries to postPhoto in one thread and then immediately getData in another thread, the getData thread will have to wait until the postPhoto thread is finished before it starts getting data. Since all my web requests go through this class and all the methods are synchronized, that means they're essentially queued up correct?

```
public class Controller {

public synchronized static String getData(String url, String limit) { ... }

public synchronized static String postPhoto(String filepath, int server_id) { ... }

public synchronized static InputStream getPhoto(String thumbnailPath) { ... }

public synchronized static String createIncident(String name, String description) { ... }

public synchronized static String updatePerson() { ... }

synchronized static boolean verifyConnection(String response) { ... }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I probably should have mentioned that even though some of the above methods are called createIncident or updatePerson, all of them ONLY make httprequests, the code inside all of the methods is generally the same except for important minor variations. In other parts of my code, I spin off threads to call these methods, and that's the part I was asking about. Since those threads call these methods, thread B that is calling getData will have to wait until thread A finishes it's part of postPhoto.

Comment: The idea behind most queues is to allow the producer and consumer work concurrently.  In this case you will serialize your requests, but your "producers" will block when the "consumer" is busy.

Comment: Just to clarify what @Peter said: Your code is basically not multi-threaded as it is, which is probably not what you want.  It certainly is safely synchronized, but so much so that you can only have the performance corresponding to a single core on multi-core hardware.

Comment: I'm going to clarify. I think I left some important information out of the original question

Comment: After reading you edit it seems that your over-synchronization is even more of a problem than I thought. When a method makes a httprequest it holds the lock to Controller.class, so no other method can be running while you are waiting for the reply... which could be a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your implementation as well. 
Is your controller singleton or instance per thread?
do your methods use shared objects?

If singleton and methods sharing objects, then there is no guarantee for thread1 to run postPhoto and then immediately after that getData even if you call sequentially. Another thread may take the turn and start running in between thread1 calling those 2 methods.

Bear in mind, synchronized keyword locks on the class itself so at any time there will be only one method executing. No 2 synchronized methods will be run at the same time.

Comment: All methods are static, so it does not matter if it's a singleton.

Comment: yes, the part we see all static but there may be some instance methods as well, we dont see the whole code.

Comment: Yeah it's not a singleton, and all methods are static. The last part of your answer is what I needed I think. Since they're static, and synchronized locks on the class, at any time only one method will be executing. I know the order won't be enforced, but I'm alright with that. As long as it's one at a time

Comment: If thats what you were looking for, thats good then. I thought maybe you have soem other methods as well not static in the class.

Comment: @Josh By the way since you only have static methods, you should have no constructor (`private Controller() { }`) and always call `Controller.someStaticMethod()`.  I personally think they should not allow calling static methods on instances (`constroller1.someStaticMethod();`) in Java, or any language.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do. No constructor, and always calling Controller.whatever. Thanks for the advice though. This was really helpful and saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The combination of `synchronized` and `static` guarantees what you want.